# PHP $obj->{$field} equivalent in Python

Tags: python, php, oop, attributes

In **PHP** we can refer to an attribute of an object dynamically like this `$obj->{$field}`.

How can the same thing be achieved in python?

Comment: This might help. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0363/

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of an attribute dynamically, you can use [`getattr(obj, field_name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

To set the value dynamically, you can use [`setattr(obj, field_name, new_value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

To test whether the attribute exists, like `isset` in PHP, you can use [`hasattr(obj, field_name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr).